# SonarQube deprecated rule suggestions missing

Tags: sonarqube

On SonarQube 5.2 (after successive upgrade, not test on fresh now install) I managed my quatlity profile by removing all deprecated rules and replace them by suggested one.

But for rule **Correctness - Integer multiply of result of integer remainder**, findbugs:IM_MULTIPLYING_RESULT_OF_IREM, the suggested one is **S00864**. But the link does not give me the rule accessible throw the link /coding_rules#rule_key=squid:S00864

Same thing for rule **Ncss Type Count**, findbugs:AIM_MULTIPLYING_RESULT_OF_IREM, suggested one is **InsufficientCommentDensity** accessible throw the link /coding_rules#rule_key=squid:InsufficientCommentDensity

May be suggested are were previously deleted ? Does someone have those rules in SonarQube instance ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi this seems to be a bug in deprecation link as the rule is numbered S864 (without the zeros) see : http://nemo.sonarqube.org/coding_rules#rule_key=squid%3AS864

This one is already fixed (see https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-findbugs/blob/master/src/main/resources/org/sonar/l10n/findbugs/rules/findbugs/IM_MULTIPLYING_RESULT_OF_IREM.html) but not yet released.

And for the other one, the repository is not correct, it is not in squid repository but in common-java : see http://nemo.sonarqube.org/coding_rules#rule_key=common-java%3AInsufficientCommentDensity

Can you reprecise which rule exactly generate this 2nd broken link ? so we can fix it.

Comment: Can I take a break ? You guys reply to fast.
Any way for the second one : the url is /api/rules/show?key=pmd%3ANcssTypeCount
key : pmd:NcssTypeCount

Comment: And so it is fixed : https://github.com/SonarCommunity/sonar-pmd/commit/d17f70f7030adc04cda3e9215d47d5c6a891b19c :) Should be available in next pmd release... (no plan for that as of today)

Answer (score 2):

The rules still exist, but (as you noticed) the links are wrong.

The correct link paths are:

- /coding_rules#rule_key=common-java%3AInsufficientCommentDensity
- /coding_rules#rule_key=squid%3AS864